# Marshal out parameter that is a reference type

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I'm trying to get a C# class (not struct!) from a C++ function back (using out parameter). This is the C# side:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class OutClass
{
    public int X;
}

// This interface function will be mapped to the C++ function
void MarshalOutClass(out OutClass outClass);
```

The C++ part looks like this

```
struct OutClass
{
    int x = 0;
};

extern "C" MARSHAL_TESTS_API void MarshalOutClass(OutClass** out);
```

The function mapping works via a custom mechanism and is not part of this question. All marshaling attributes are treated normally.

In C#, we usually declare out arguments inline, like:

```
MarshalOutClass(out var outClass);
DoSomething(outClass);
```

Since C# reference types are marshaled by pointer, I figured I would have to add another pointer for `ref` or `out` parameters. So I use `OutClass**` on the C++ side.

I **assume** that C# translates the

```
MarshalOutClass(out var outClass);
```

part to roughly

```
OutClass outClass = default(OutClass);
MarshalOutClass(ref outClass);
```

which is a reference to `null`, or on C++ side: a pointer to a `nullptr`. This wouldn't be a problem for C# value types (aka `struct`) because their default is a default constructed instance.

This means, I'd have to manually create an instance of my object on the C++ side and marshal it back to C#.

```
void MarshalOutClass(OutClass** out)
{
    auto ptr = static_cast<OutClass*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(OutClass)));
    *ptr = OutClass{};
    *out = ptr;
}
```

The code seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm leaking memory with this or if the marshaler is going to to take care of it properly. I don't do any cleanup on the C# side.

This brings me to the following questions:

1. is my assumption on how `ref` and `out` are translated to C++ correct?
2. is `CoTaskMemAlloc` the correct function here?
3. do I have to perform any additional memory management related tasks (on either side)?
4. is the overall approach correct here? What should I do differently?

I know that `static_cast<OutClass*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(OutClass)))` is a bit sketchy here but lets assume `OutClass` is always a trivial type.

Comment: Have you already considered [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions#systime-sample)?

Comment: @dymanoid yes I've seen this example. There is a difference to my problem tho: I'm not allocating the object on the C# side, but the C++ side.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't have any confidence that this will work correctly. I can't imagine the marshaller knowing how to free a random pointer correctly. If you want to go down this route (and other routes will probably be easier, if you can!), then I'd explicitly use `IntPtr`, `Marshal.PtrToStructure` and `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`

Comment: You'd probably need a custom marshaler for this, take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618837/c-sharp-marshal-unmanaged-pointer-return-type).

Comment: @canton7 what would be the easier way to get a class over to C#? Allocating it on the C# side and use the `OutAttribute`?

Comment: @Timo Why are you trying to achieve this? Why do you need to use a class here?

Comment: @canton7 just curiosity. I know several ways to work around my problem, I just wanted to know how hard it can be and if it can be done in a somewhat elegant way.

Comment: In my understanding (and I could be wrong), the memory layouts of objects in C++ and C# are fundamentally incompatible. E.g. C# has an object header, which C++ is going to know nothing about. So you can't have a single object and pass it between C++ and C#: you need to have a native object and a managed object, and copy data between them. The marshaller normally hides all of this from you. If you wanted to get a pointer to a C++ object into C#-land, use IntPtr, but that's not a C# object. I can't imagine passing a pointer to a managed object into C++ going well.

Comment: [Make sure you've read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior) (and the other related sections). Passing classes around using p/invoke is a COM thing with COM-specific behaviours

Comment: @canton7 I'm aware that I'm not actually allocating a C# object on the C++ side. I still use the C++ type for the `CoTaskMemAlloc`. The marshaler still performs the conversion between the unmanaged and managed part. I thought, since it usually has to allocate memory anyway (to copy managed data into unmanaged objects), that it will clean up that memory afterwards using `CoTaskMemFree(out)` or `CoTaskMemFree(*out)`.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know for sure, but I can't imagine it would. How does it know that you allocated it with `CoTaskMemAlloc`, rather than `malloc` or `new` or something else? How does it know that it's even a heap-allocated object, and doesn't have static storage? It simply doesn't have enough information: the only thing it can do is assume that it hasn't been given ownership of the object.